# Jsoup.clean without adding html entities

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-entities

I'm cleaning some text from unwanted HTML tags (such as `<script>`) by using

```
String clean = Jsoup.clean(someInput, Whitelist.basicWithImages());
```

The problem is that it replaces for instance `å` with `&aring;` (which causes troubles for me since it's not "pure xml").

For example

```
Jsoup.clean("hello å <script></script> world", Whitelist.basicWithImages())
```

yields

```
"hello &aring;  world"
```

but I would like

```
"hello å  world"
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this? (I.e. simpler than converting `&aring;` back to `å` in the result.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can configure Jsoup's escaping mode: Using `EscapeMode.xhtml` will give you output w/o entities.

Here's a complete snippet that accepts `str` as input, and cleans it using `Whitelist.simpleText()`:

```
// Parse str into a Document
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);

// Clean the document.
doc = new Cleaner(Whitelist.simpleText()).clean(doc);

// Adjust escape mode
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);

// Get back the string of the body.
str = doc.body().html();
```

Comment: Note: Rather than interacting directly with a [Cleaner object](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.html), use the [clean methods](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#clean-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist-) in Jsoup.

Answer (score 11):

There are already feature requests on the website of Jsoup. You can extend source code yourself by adding a new empty Map and a new escaping type. If you don't want to do this you can use StringEscapeUtils from apache commons.

```
public static String getTextOnlyFromHtmlText(String htmlText){
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse( htmlText );
    doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");
    htmlText = Jsoup.clean( doc.body().html(), Whitelist.simpleText() );
    htmlText = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(htmlText);
    return htmlText;
}
```

Comment: good point with the StringEscapeUtils method Frank. Very useful, not only in this case

Comment: @frandevel This would be a very bad idea. If the input is `&lt;script&gt;alert('Hello');&lt;/script&gt;`, you will actually inject unsafe HTML and allow XSS attack.

Comment: This functionality is now implemented i Jsoup. See Parser.unescapeEntities, https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Interesting point, then How do you clean inputs like this `&lt;script&gt;alert('Hello');&lt;/script&gt;` ?

Answer (score 5):

Answer from &bmoc is working fine, but you could use a shorter solution :

```
// Clean html
Jsoup.clean(someInput, "yourBaseUriOrEmpty", Whitelist.simpleText(), new OutputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml))
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to do this is

```
// clean the html
String output = Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.basicWithImages());

// Parse string into a document
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(output);

// Adjust escape mode
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);

// Get back the string
System.out.println(doc.body().html());
```

I have tested this and it works

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is using `Jsoup.parse` which seems more heavyweight than what is going on in `Jsoup.clean` after a quick glance at the source.

I copied the source code of `Jsoup.clean(...)` and added the line to set the escape mode. This should avoid some unecessary steps done by the parse method because it doesn't have to parse a whole html document but just handle a fragment.

```
private String clean(String html, Whitelist whitelist) {
    Document dirty = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html, "");
    Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(whitelist);
    Document clean = cleaner.clean(dirty);
    clean.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
    return clean.body().html();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
EscapeMode em = EscapeMode.xhtml;
em.getMap().clear();

doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(em);
```

This will remove **ALL** html entities, including these: *', ", & ,< and >*. The *EscapeMode.xhtml* allows these entities.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the HTML as a Document, then use a Cleaner to clean the document and generate another one, get the outputSettings of the document and set the appropriate charset and the escape mode to xhtml, then transform the document to a String. Not tested, but should work.