# Jsoup clean title tag failure

Tags: java, html, xml, jsoup

I am using Jsoup 1.9.2 to process and clean some XML input of specific tags. During this, I noticed that Jsoup behaves strangely when it is asked to clean `title` tags. Specifically, other XML tags within the `title` tag do not get removed, and in fact get replaced by their escaped forms.

I created a short unit test for this as below. The test fails, as `output` comes out with the value of `CuCl&lt;sub&gt;2&lt;/sub&gt;`.

```
@Test
public void stripXmlSubInTitle() {
    final String input = "<title>CuCl<sub>2</sub></title>";
    final String output = Jsoup.clean(input, Whitelist.none());
    assertEquals("CuCl2", output);
}
```

If the `title` tag is replaced with other tags (e.g., `p` or `div`), then everything works as expected. Any explanation and workaround will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683018/jsoup-clean-without-adding-html-entities

Answer (score 0):

The `title` tag should be used within the `head` (or in HTML5 within the `html`) tag. Since it is used to display the title of the HTML document, mostly in a browser window/tab, it is not supposed to have child tags.

JSoup treats it differently than actual content tags like `p` or `div`, the same applies for `textarea`.

Edit:

You could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        final String input = "<content><title>CuCl<sub>2</sub></title><othertag>blabla</othertag><title>title with no subtags</title></content>";
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(input);
        Elements titles = document.getElementsByTag("title");
        for (Element element : titles) {
            element.text(Jsoup.clean(element.ownText(), Whitelist.none()));
        }
        System.out.println(document.body().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That would return:

```
<body>
 <content>
  <title>CuCl2</title>
  <othertag>
   blabla
  </othertag>
  <title>title with no subtags</title>
 </content>
</body>
```

Depending on your needs, some adjustments need to be made, e.g.

```
System.out.println(Jsoup.clean(document.body().toString(), Whitelist.none()));
```

That would return:

```
CuCl2  blabla  title with no subtags
```

Comment: Thanks! My documents are not pure HTML though, they're XML with some (incidentally) HTML tags. Can you recommend a way to avoid this (other than a regex replacement)? I like/need the Whitelist bit of Jsoup.